# 2015 Hyundai Genesis - Ticking Noise in Engine

Tags: noise, hyundai, oil-change, genesis-sedan

2015 Hyundai Genesis Sedan
3.8L
24000 km

My car is making a ticking noise in the engine. Almost like a muffled playing card in bike spokes. I especially noticed it after an oil change, but I seem to recall it being there before as well.

After the car warms up the noise disappears.
The noise does not seem to be tied to RPM, however I don’t hear it until I start accelerating. It just doesn’t get any faster with rpm.
I don’t have any codes or fluid leaks. 
Oil levels are normal.

Any ideas what this could be? What can I try doing to resolve this?

- [Engine at cold idle. No noise.](https://youtu.be/AeZr96ZNA0A) (Warning: loud)
- [Engine ticking while driving.](https://youtu.be/JwCsWKUDFtM)

`0:18` ticking starts.

`0:34` I rev the car into higher RPMs to show the noise persists though RPM at the same frequency.
Ticking noises will come and go throughout the video.

- [Car after the short drive in the garage. No ticking.](https://youtu.be/-Z_DPkS6-_I)

The car only seems to make noise when its moving.

- Oil level.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Anyway you could get some video/audio of the noise? Not being rpm dependent is strange.

Comment: Posted some videos of the noise while driving. Also posted videos of the car idle before and after the drive as well as the oil level.

Comment: I can hear the noise you're talking about, but have no clue what it is. Very strange noise. I do, however, have a suggestion for you. I'd suspect you have the same basic warranty coverage in BC as we do here in the States. You are well within your Bumper-to-Bumper warranty period and mileage. Take it to the dealership and have them figure it out for you.

Answer (score 1):

It can be the plastic cover under the car.

I have a 2016 3.8 and it did the same thing and drove me crazy trying to figure it out.  By accident, my dealer fixed a button screw that had popped out of a plastic cover underneath my car.  When I left the dealer the ticking was gone.  This morning it was cold and still gone.  I always thought it was sort of a Bernoulli Principle at work and something started fluttering when my car hit 25 mph and then stopped around 35mph.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've reworded it slightly so it does not look like a forum-like "it happens to me too" post.